# Javascript look-up function optimization

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm writing a custom function for my Google Sheet using Javascript, it should basically return the value based upon a table.

I've got something that works, but feels extremely ugly with lots of nested if statements. How could this be improved for readability?

```
function price(msrp, order_quantity) 
{
  var percentage;
  if(order_quantity >= 200 && order_quantity <= 400) {
    if(msrp >=49 && msrp <= 99) {
      percentage = 0.07;
    } else if (msrp >=100 && msrp <= 249) {
      percentage = 0.06;
    } else if (msrp >=250 && msrp <= 499) {
      percentage = 0.05;
    } else if (msrp >=500) {
      percentage = 0.04;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } else if (order_quantity >= 500 && order_quantity <= 900)  {
    if(msrp >=49 && msrp <= 99) {
      percentage = 0.06;
    } else if (msrp >=100 && msrp <= 249) {
      percentage = 0.05;
    } else if (msrp >=250 && msrp <= 499) {
      percentage = 0.04;
    } else if (msrp >=500) {
      percentage = 0.03;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } else if (order_quantity >= 1000 && order_quantity <= 1400)  {
    if(msrp >=49 && msrp <= 99) {
      percentage = 0.07;
    } else if (msrp >=100 && msrp <= 249) {
      percentage = 0.06;
    } else if (msrp >=250 && msrp <= 499) {
      percentage = 0.05;
    } else if (msrp >=500) {
      percentage = 0.04;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } else if (order_quantity >= 1500)  {
    if(msrp >=49 && msrp <= 99) {
      percentage = 0.04;
    } else if (msrp >=100 && msrp <= 249) {
      percentage = 0.03;
    } else if (msrp >=250 && msrp <= 499) {
      percentage = 0.025;
    } else if (msrp >=500) {
      percentage = 0.015;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
  return msrp * percentage;
}
```

Comment: seems odd that you have gaps in the quantity from 401...499 and 901...999 and 1401...1499 - makes things a little more complex, but not too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define all of your levels in arrays and use for instance [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function price (msrp, order_quantity) {
    var percentageLevels = [
                [0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04],
                [0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03],
                [0.04, 0.03, 0.025, 0.015]
            ],
            quantityLevels = [
                { min: 200, max: 400, percentages: percentageLevels[0] },
                { min: 500, max: 900, percentages: percentageLevels[1] },
                { min: 1000, max: 1400, percentages: percentageLevels[0] },
                { min: 1500, max: Number.MAX_VALUE, percentages: percentageLevels[2] }
            ],
            msrpLevels = [
                { min: 49, max: 99 },
                { min: 100, max: 249 },
                { min: 250, max: 499 },
                { min: 500, max: Number.MAX_VALUE }
            ],
            percentages = (quantityLevels.filter(function (q) {
                return q.min <= order_quantity && order_quantity <= q.max;
            })[0] || {}).percentages,
            foundMsrp = percentages ? msrpLevels.filter(function (m, i) {
                msrpLevels[i].percentage = percentages[i];

                return m.min <= msrp && msrp <= m.max;
            })[0] : null;

    if (!percentages || !foundMsrp) {
        return null;
    }

    return msrp * foundMsrp.percentage;
};
```

The call to `quantityLevels.filter()` will find which quantityLevel the order_quantity falls into, if any, and the call to `msprLevels.filter()` maps the percentage value to each msprLevel and only returns the level that matches so you know that if `foundMspr` has a value then `foundMspr.percentage` now has the percentage multiplier you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `msrp` ranges are the same for each `order_quantity` case, you could cut it down from three sections to one by indexing your percentages. For example you could say:

```
var pct = [];
pct[0] = [0.07, 0.06, 0.05, 0.04];
pct[1] = [0.06, 0.05, 0.04, 0.03];
// don't need the third since it's the same as the first
pct[2] = [0.04, 0.03, 0.025, 0.015];
var k, percentage;
if (order_quantity >= 200 && order_quantity <= 400) k=0;
else if (order_quantity >= 500 && order_quantity <= 900) k=1;
else if (order_quantity >= 1000 && order_quantity <= 1400) k=0;
else if (order_quantity >= 1500) k=2;
else return null;
if(msrp >=49 && msrp <= 99) percentage = pct[k][0];
else if (msrp >=100 && msrp <= 249) percentage = pct[k][1];
else if (msrp >=250 && msrp <= 499) percentage = pct[k][2];
else if (msrp >=500) percentage = pct[k][3];
else return null;
return msrp * percentage;
```

It's still not the most elegant method, but it's a little easier to read.